# In a column(quantity) I have some values of type double and N/A too . How to sort both using Comparator?

Tags: java

In a column(quantity) I have some values of type double and N/A too.

In my comparator class compare method, this is the coding mentioned below

```
   if(double1 == double2) {
        return 0;
    }

    // We know that both aren't null, so if only long 2 is null, 1 > 2
    if(double2 == null) {
        return 1;
    }

    // We know that both aren't null, so if only long 1 is null, 1 < 2
    if(double1 == null) {
        return -1;
    }

    // Nulls are handled, use the native compare
    return double1.compareTo(double2);
```

double1 and double2 is of type Double.

It gives Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "N/A" .

Please give me the solution.

Comment: Where are you using these `Double`s?  You're putting in "N/A" someplace which isn't appropriate.

Comment: Post more of the stacktrace, the line number should be there where the exception is actually occurring. `Double` cannot be instantiated with "N/A" as the value.

Comment: What should be sorted first, `N/A` or `null`?

Comment: In ascending N/A will be sorted first. Need of ascending only.

Answer (score 0):

It's my guess (I can't really say without seeing how you're using these Doubles) that you're looking to hold a value that doesn't really exist, and a value that may.

To that end, I would say that you construct your `Double` with [`Double.NaN`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#NaN) as so:

```
Double double1 = new Double(Double.NaN);
```

I'm not sure if NaN is defined for a sorting operation - it holds no intricate order since it's just not a number.  You may want to use an auxiliary structure, such as a `List<Double>`, to first comb through the `Double`s that aren't a number, and place them first.  Then, you could sort the remaining `Double`s.